# Certified receipt from IRS

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, mailing

We need to send a certified letter (return receipt) to the IRS for a insolvent estate.  What is the address?

Comment: IRS has regional offices. It varies by state.

Answer (score 3):

In general the IRS directs you to send mail either by region or by type of form. The best source is the main form that you are submitting to the IRS. It should have a list of addresses either on the form or in the instructions.

You can get a certificate of mailing from the post office if you are wanting to prove you mailed something by a deadline. It doesn't require a signature at the IRS end.